# How to recover deleted files from CF card？

Tags: data-recovery

How to recover deleted files from CF card？Which Compact Flash Data Recovery Freeware is better? Recommend it to me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Photorec is exactly that searching you for. One thing should be mentioned, however, its console application so you will have to be ready for it.
You can install it by using `sudo apt install testdisk` and start by typing `sudo photorec` in terminal emulator.

There is some step-by-step guides which may help you https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step ,

https://recoverit.wondershare.com/photo-recovery/how-to-use-photorec.html (this one recommends another software as ad, but i'd rather stick with Photorec)

Comment: PhotoRec technically runs in a terminal, but it does have menus and ascii "graphics", and can be run with little more than arrows and enter. A link to it's how-to pages might help